# Can't remote-debug Java on EC2 instance

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, remote-debugging

On my **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** instance I have installed **openjdk 10.0.2** and try to run my Java application with either of these commands:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=y -jar myJar.jar

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y -jar myJar.jar
```

Both times it says:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

All looking good. In my instance's security group, I have even opened up all trafic from any source, just to be sure.

[image: Instance's Security Group Rules]

I can `ping` the instance from my local machine successfully, the one I want to start the remote debug session from. Yet when I launch the session targeting the instance's public IP and port 8000, **Eclipse Photon** (4.8.0) says:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

I've done it all before on a Linux machine with Java 8 installed and it worked fine. On my local machine, I'm running **Java 10.0.2**.

Does it have something to do with the Java versions?